# How to test if nodes and its subnodes are empty?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

Ho can i test nodes like this if empty?

```
<Address>
  <Street></Street>
  <Building></Building>
  <Postcode></Postcode>
  <Town></Town>
  <State></State>
  <Country></Country>
</Address>
```

Comment: Check it with `NodeName=''`, for example `<xsl:if test="Street=''">...`

Comment: It depends on how you define "empty". `Address` is not empty: it contains 6 child elements.

Answer (score 1):

you can test if a node and its subnodes are empty by:

```
<xsl:if test="normalize-space(.)=''">All nodes empty: true&#xA;</xsl:if>
```

or, you can test if it has an empty node by:

```
<xsl:if test="normalize-space(*)=''">Contains an empty node: true&#xA;</xsl:if>
```

when this stylesheet is run against your input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Address">
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space(.)=''">All nodes empty: true&#xA;</xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space(*)=''">Contains an empty node: true&#xA;</xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it will yield:

```
All nodes empty: true
Contains an empty node: true
```

See it in [action](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiKs).